# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.generateSignedData

Tags: java

I am trying to sign a simple jar, but after i signjar i get this error, My keystore and jarsigner are in the same folder as my project.

Any help would be appreciated!

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.generateSignedData([B[Ljava/security/cert/X509Certificate;[BLjava/lang/String;Ljava/net/URI;Ljava/lang/String;)[B
        at sun.security.tools.jarsigner.TimestampedSigner.generateSignedData(TimestampedSigner.java:135)
        at sun.security.tools.jarsigner.SignatureFile$Block.<init>(Main.java:2378)
        at sun.security.tools.jarsigner.SignatureFile.generateBlock(Main.java:2276)
        at sun.security.tools.jarsigner.Main.signJar(Main.java:1272)
        at sun.security.tools.jarsigner.Main.run(Main.java:240)
        at sun.security.tools.jarsigner.Main.main(Main.java:104)

C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\Lab10\Java Certificates\Java Certificates\bin>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_192

C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\Lab10\Java Certificates\Java Certificates\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_192"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Please provide the command line that led to this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to use a method that not exits in your running libraries. Maybe the method itself or more probally some parameter.

Try to sign your jar with other version of Java instead 8, maybe Version 5 or 7 could works for you.